# Obtener parámetros de una petición PUT/DELETE

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un tipo de REST, pero cómo puedo obtener los parámetros enviados si el método es PUT o DELETE. Sé que para GET/POST existe $_REQUEST pero que hay de los otros dos, no puedo obtener la información.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT'){
  echo $_REQUEST['foo']; //Undefined
  echo $_GET['foo']; //Undefined
  echo $_POST['foo']; //Undefined
  echo $_PUT['foo']; //Esta no esxiste
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Hay que parsear el `php://input` onda:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$put_vars);
    echo $put_vars['foo'];
}
```