# PHP Obtener los parámetros de las peticiones PUT, DELETE, etc

Tags: php, http

Como todos sabemos, en PHP podemos obtener los parámetros **GET** y **POST** con sus respectivas variables globales (`$_GET` y `$_POST`), pero para el caso de **PUT**, **DELETE**, **PATCH** y tal vez otros métodos HTTP, vemos que PHP no lo gestiona por nosotros.

He probado con la [única solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177063/obtener-par%C3%A1metros-de-una-petici%C3%B3n-put-delete) que he encontrado en todos los sitios / foros y no consigo el resultado que supuestamente debería tener:

#### 1º Prueba:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$put_vars);
    echo $put_vars['name'];
}
```

Resultado:

```
Notice:  Undefined index: name in C:\...\UpdateController.php on line 9
```

#### 2º Prueba:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$put_vars);
    var_dump($put_vars);
}
```

Resultado:

```
array(1) {
  ["----------------------------531981617569841925398802
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name"]=>
  string(89) ""name"

Mi nombre y apellidos
----------------------------531981617569841925398802--
"
  }
```

#### Edit:

Me acabo de enterar de que esa información "rara" de la 2º prueba se meustran porque uso Postman para las pruebas de la API. He usado una extensión de chrome y me funciona correctamente. Ahora el problema es otro...

Comment: He probado con file_get_contents("php://input") utilizando formdata y put y recibo correctamente los datos. Lo que necesitas es parsear para acceder a las variables/valor ?

Comment: ¿Estas intentado subir **un solo archivo** via `PUT`? Si es ese el caso, entonces [esta es tu solución](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.put-method.php)

Comment: @toto me acabo de dar cuenta de que es porque uso Postman para las pruebas de la API, y este añade esos datos.

Comment: @Marcos No, se trata de una API y quiero usar el método PUT para actualizar datos, el POST para crear datos, Delete, etc...

Comment: @BrahimKhallota, no uso POSTMAN, pero se me ocurre que el problema es como lo estas configurando para enviar los datos, ya que parece que estas usando `multipart/form-data`. Si es así, solo tenes que cambiar eso a algo como `query-params`

Comment: @Marcos ¡Es cierto! Muchísimas gracias, aunque no he encontrado la opción `query-params`, con `x-www-form-urlencoded` funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @BrahimKhallota, seria bueno para la comunidad que respondas a tu propia pregunta con la solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente el problema era otro, pero básicamente, para los que no sepan cómo obtener los datos de las peticiones PUT, DELETE, PATCH, etc, [esta solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177063/obtener-par%C3%A1metros-de-una-petici%C3%B3n-put-delete) sí que es válida.

Para los que no les haya funcionado esa solución, como a mí, resulta que es porque a la hora de enviar la petición, **he enviado los datos en** `multipart/form-data` (como ha dicho Marcos en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/382369/php-obtener-los-par%C3%A1metros-de-las-peticiones-put-delete-etc?noredirect=1#comment685032_382369)).

En mi caso he podido modificar el "formato" a `x-www-form-urlencoded` en las opciones de Postman muy fácilmente, y ya me funciona a la perfección:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]